# Checking if a date is in between multiple date ranges in a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I tried my best to solve it but I could not. It would be great if you could help me on this.

I have these two arrays..

$firstarray — it contains a date [0] and the product cost [1] on that day.

```
[0] => Array (
    [0] => 2020-12-01
    [1] => 24.00
    )
[1] => Array (
    [0] => 2020-12-05
    [1] => 16.00
    )
[2] => Array (
    [0] => 2020-12-07
    [1] => 12.00
    )
[3] => Array (
    [0] => 2020-12-15
    [1] => 0.00
    )
[4] => Array (
    [0] => 2020-12-16
    [1] => 0.00
    )
[5] => Array (
    [0] => 2020-12-16
    [1] => 100.00
    )
```

$secondarray — contains multiple date ranges [0] and [1], where the cost [2] is exceptionally different within the given period.

```
[0] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-01
        [1] => 2020-12-05
        [2] => 42.00
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-06
        [1] => 2020-12-08
        [2] => 35.00
        )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-09
        [1] => 2020-12-12
        [2] => 76.00
        )
    )
[1] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-01
        [1] => 2020-12-05
        [2] => 42.00
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-06
        [1] => 2020-12-08
        [2] => 35.00
        )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-09
        [1] => 2020-12-12
        [2] => 76.00
        )
    )
[2] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-04
        [1] => 2020-12-09
        [2] => 10.00
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-10
        [1] => 2020-12-13
        [2] => 45.00
        )
    )
[3] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-04
        [1] => 2020-12-09
        [2] => 10.00
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-10
        [1] => 2020-12-13
        [2] => 45.00
        )
    )
[4] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-04
        [1] => 2020-12-09
        [2] => 10.00
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-10
        [1] => 2020-12-13
        [2] => 45.00
        )
    )
[5] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-01
        [1] => 2020-12-05
        [2] => 42.00
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-06
        [1] => 2020-12-08
        [2] => 35.00
        )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-09
        [1] => 2020-12-12
        [2] => 76.00
        )
    )
```

I want to check if each date in $firstarray is in between one of the date ranges in the $secondarray, if so — echo the value at index [2] from the $secondarray from that date range, if not — echo the value at index [1] from the $firstarray.

Both arrays will always have the same number, which is **5** in this case (the foreach loop should happen always for that same index only) but the number of the arrays or the date ranges inside could be different.

thank you very much!!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Do you want to compare each date in `$firstarray` with *all* the ranges in `$secondarray`, or only the ranges for the corresponding index?

Comment: hi nick, no only for the date ranges in the corresponding index!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop over the values in `$firstarray`, setting the default price as the value from that array. You can then use the key from each value to index into `$secondarray` and compare the date from `$firstarray` with each of the ranges in `$secondarray`. If the date is in the range, set the price to the value from that range.

```
$prices = array();
foreach ($firstarray as $key => $value) {
    $price = $value[1];
    foreach ($secondarray[$key] as $range) {
        if ($value[0] >= $range[0] && $value[0] <= $range[1]) {
            $price = $range[2];
            break;
        }
    }
    $prices[] = $price;
}

print_r($prices);
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 42
    [1] => 42
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 100
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/8vltM)

Comment: wow! thank you very much nick, i really appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

This checks if date of first array is between any of the date-ranges of the second array. If you want to check other indexes just increment (or decrement) $index.

To return the correct price just uncomment the

```
return $firstarray[1]
and
return $secondarray[2]
```

## Output

```
Is between
Is not there
Is not there
```

## Code

```
<?php
/*

================ Firstarray
[0] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-01
        [1] => 24.00
    )

================ Secondarray
[0] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-01
        [1] => 2020-12-05
        [2] => 42.00
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-06
        [1] => 2020-12-08
        [2] => 35.00
        )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => 2020-12-09
        [1] => 2020-12-12
        [2] => 76.00
    )
*/

$firstarray = array(array('2020-12-01', '24.00'));
$secondarray = array(array(array('2020-12-01', '2020-12-05', '42.00'), array('2020-12-06', '2020-12-08', '35.00'), array('2020-12-09', '2020-12-12', '76.00')));

$index = 0;
echo check($firstarray[$index], $secondarray[$index]);

function check($firstarray, $secondarray)
{
    foreach ($secondarray as $key => $value) {
        if (
            // Check if date is between two dates
            (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($firstarray[0])) >= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value[0]))) && 
            (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($firstarray[0])) <= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value[1])))) 
        {
            echo "Is between".PHP_EOL;
            // return $secondarray[2];
        } else {
            echo "Is not there".PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    
    // return $firstarray[1];
}
```